# Kuberenets POD content not rendering - Nginx Ingress Controller Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I had setup the nginx ingress controller and installed two applications with based path routing. Basic nginx application service is routing to "/" path and another UI application service is routing to "/help" path.

Ingress file for basic Nginx application which is rendering properly as per image attached,

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360s"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: haproxy-ingress.nxt-insights.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Another ingress file created for UI application which content is not rendering properly as per image attached,

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helpdoc-nxthelpdoc-register-app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360s"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: haproxy-ingress.nxt-insights.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /help
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: helpdoc-nxthelpdoc-register-app
            port:
              number: 80
```

**Note:-** UI Application is rendering properly if i tried to access it using nodeport in the browser.

Thanks in advance. Kindly help me out to resolve the issue

#kubernetes #nginx-ingress #ingresscontroller

I used the below repo to install nginx-ingress controller,

`helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx`

and performed the actions whatever i narrated above question.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.